# Where are the PyTorch python bindings to C++?

Tags: pytorch

I need to know, for a given function in the python api of PyTorch, how to find the corresponding C/++ code that it maps to underneath.

Better yet, if it is possible, for a given python function that is bound to some C/++ function in a loaded library, how to know the name of that c++ function for a given python function?

Comment: try to compile it form source and look at the files in `torch/csrc/autograd/generated`

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ATen](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/aten)

It exposes the Tensor operations in Torch and PyTorch in C++11. In the README you should find all the relevant information.

I don't think it's possible to know the C++ function bound to a Python function in general.